# Insertar datos por consola en una base de datos MySQL con java en Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, poo

Buen día a todos ,  tengo un programa hecho en java , en donde tengo que insertar una clave de un usuario que se ingrese por consola, cifrar dicha clave con un método de hashing ( en este caso plegamiento ) y después de eso guardar la clave cifrada en una base de datos , en este caso MySQL, sin embargo tengo un error en el stmt.setInt, es la primera vez que intento insertar datos de java en una tabla de MySQL , les dejo mi código para ver si lo estoy haciendo bien. Gracias por su ayuda.

Este es el error que sale al correr el programa:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method setInt(int, int) is undefined for the type Statement

    at conexionBase/enlace.TestConexion.main(TestConexion.java:27)
```

Cabe aclarar que el método donde se hace el cifrado es el primer try, el otro try y catch es donde estoy queriendo guardar los datos en MySQL.

```
package enlace;
import java.util.*; 
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class TestConexión {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connect conexion = new Connect(); 
    conexion.conectar(); 
     try (Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in)) {
         System.out.println("Ingrese su numero de empleado");
         String numero = entrada.next();
         int num=0; 
         char[] numeroEmpleado=numero.toCharArray(); 
         for (int r = 0; r < numeroEmpleado.length; r++) {
              num = num + numeroEmpleado[r];
         } 
         System.out.println("Hash de tu numero de empleado : " + num);
      
         
         try {
         Connect con = new Connect(); 
         Statement stmt;
         stmt=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO empleados(num_empleados) VALUES (?)");
         int mero = num;
         stmt.setInt(1,mero);
         stmt.executeUpdate(numero, args);
         stmt.close();
         }catch(SQLException e){
              System.out.println("Error!, la llamada no pudo ser agregada a la base de datos.");
         }
     
  }
     
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/570559/edit) y adjuntar el texto del error que dices que tienes y con que entrada ocurre? Así será mucho mas facil que recibas ayuda.

Comment: Bueno, uno de los errores es muy obvio. ¿Cómo vas a llamar a un método de un objeto que es nulo? Primero declaras `Connect con = null;` y dos líneas después en `con.prepareStatement` intentas sacar un método de ese objeto nulo, eso no tiene sentido.

Comment: Listo ya edite la pregunta y cambie el primer error que me aclaraste  gracias Jaime

Comment: Luis, sigo viendo el error de `con` declarado como `null` y luego intentas invocar `prepareStatement`  de algo `null`. Por favor, edita tu código. Agrega también el código de tu clase `Connect`.

Comment: Estás declarando el objeto del tipo `Statement`, pero esos objetos no tienen métodos para setear, debes declarlarlo así: **`PreparedStatement stmt;`** pues lo que se requiere aquí es una consulta preparada. Por otra parte, revisa con calma tu código, cometes errores garrafales, como conectar dos veces a la base de datos. Tampoco se entienden los dos `try`, o que vuelvas a declarar `mero` sobre una variable que debería existir preivamente ¿?

Comment: Ok, perfecto , gracias !

Comment: Define num por fuera del try-catch y revisa qué es lo que le estás sumando en el ciclo. Ya después definir ooootra variable sólo para asignarle num realmente sobra.

Comment: Además, si quieres crear un HASH  realmente deberías usar una función específica. [Ver aquí por ejemplo](https://mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/).

Comment: concuerdo con Ud A.Cedano, se que no es un hash como tal , solo que es lo que nos pidieron hacer en la clase de ciberseguridad de la escuela y aunque es algo que podríamos decir que no tiene sentido programar, fue lo que justamente nos pidieron hacer. Muchas gracias por sus aportaciones